# Implementing 0..1 relationship in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, upsert

I have a table where I would like to remove a lot of null-columns but I am unsure if I am going in the right direction.

Here is sample SQL to show what I want (removing Quantity from Products):

```
CREATE TABLE [Products]([Id] [int] NOT NULL,[Name] [varchar](50))
CREATE TABLE [StockProducts]([Id] [int] NOT NULL,[Quantity] [int])
go
insert into Products (Id, [Name]) values (1,'Socks')
insert into Products (Id, [Name]) values (2,'Gloves')
CREATE VIEW ProductStockView as select P.Id, SP.Quantity from Products P left join StockProducts SP on P.Id = SP.Id
go
select * from ProductStockView
go
update ProductStockView set Quantity = 2 where Id = 1
```

I would really like the update to give an insert in my StockProducts table, because I have all Ids from Products, and my existing code would keep working.

Is there a pattern for this, or would the preferred way just be to add an update trigger on the view? Right now the update statement gives: 0 rows affected.

Edit based on two comments: The Id of the Two tables should be considered primary keys (for use in frameworks like Entity Framework). And my real example is ofcourse that the table called Products in my example is an old table we have with 75 columns and the ProductStockView is what I would like to replace it with in parts of my code.

Comment: The *real* question here, I feel, is why are you updating the view `ProductStockView`, and not performing the update (or rather Upsert/`MERGE`) against `StockProducts`?

Comment: At a minimum, your DDL should contain the correct primary key and foreign key constraints so no one needs to guess at your intent. And it is difficult to offer useful suggestions without a much better understanding of your model. Rarely does one have a single table that represents inventory (or current stock level or whatever term is appropriate). Perhaps your model is much more simplistic and is not a real-life situation. If so, that is important information if only to avoid going into detail that is not needed.

Comment: You could use [`merge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to handle the _upsert_, i.e. `update` or `insert` as needed. It could even be trained to `delete` if the `Quantity` is zero.

Comment: Unfortunately, your options are to either replace your UPDATE statements with MERGE, as explained above, or add a trigger on the UPDATE for the table. If you would prefer not to change your UPDATE statements at all, then a trigger is your only hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. This was exactly what I needed. I'll leave the answer here:

```
create trigger ProductStockViewUpdateTrigger
on ProductStockView instead of update
as
MERGE StockProducts as target
USING (SELECT Id, Quantity from inserted) as source
    ON target.Id = source.Id
WHEN MATCHED
    AND target.Quantity != source.Quantity
        THEN UPDATE 
            SET target.Quantity = source.Quantity
WHEN NOT MATCHED by target
THEN 
    INSERT ([Id], [Quantity])
    values (source.id, source.quantity);
```